# Alternativa para checar se a janela é um popup

Tags: javascript, popup

Eu tenho uma página que pode ser aberta tanto pelo meu próprio domínio quanto externamente, tanto como uma janela "normal" quanto como um popup.

Nessa janela, eu preciso verificar se ela foi aberta como um popup ou não, e realizar algumas customizações programaticamente. Até o momento, estava usando a seguinte abordagem (amplamente recomendada):

```
if (window.opener)
    // É um popup
else
    // Não é um popup
```

Porém, tenho encontrado [problemas de compatibilidade com o **Internet Explorer**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0c014e78-8d35-4df3-93da-7f6a30b4ed8b/object-windowopenerlocationhref-is-malfunctioning-in-ie8?forum=iewebdevelopment), que faz com que o atributo `opener` não seja preenchido.

Alguém poderia me indicar alguma alternativa para realizar essa checagem?

**Obs:**

- De maneira geral, não posso alterar o código que abre a janela (ex: para incluir parâmetros de querystring)
- Quando digo abrir como popup, me refiro à uma chamada para `window.open()`.

Comment: Já considerou usar o cabeçalho [HTTP Referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) para verificar a origem da requisição no servidor e então, por exemplo, redirecionar ou incluir um script de acordo com a origem?

Comment: @utluiz Infelizmente, não é o referrer quem define a forma como a janela está sendo aberta (popup ou não)... Incluí na explicação só pra deixar entendido melhor o cenário.

Comment: Certo. Você conseguiu testar a resposta do Erik? Funcionou?

Comment: @utluiz Sim, mas de qualquer forma não será possível seguir com essa abordagem, pois isso implicaria em alterar todos os lugares que estão abrindo esse popup, e muitos deles são de outros sistemas terceiros.

Comment: Talvez minha resposta de usar `window.opener` funcione. =)

Answer (score 6):

O método `window.open` retorna o objeto da janela que foi aberta, então se for no mesmo domínio acredito que você possa adicionar um atributo no objeto window da popup depois de abrir e checar ele.

**Página que abre a popup:**

```
var pop = window.open("http://www.dominio.com");
pop.ePopup = true;
```

**Popup:**

```
if (typeof window.ePopup !== 'undefined' && window.ePopup)
    // É um popup
else
    // Não é um popup
```

Não tenho certeza quanto à compatibilidade dessa solução. E se estiver em domínios separados vai ter problema de [CORS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) que pode ser resolvido na configuração do servidor na maioria das vezes.

Comment: Infelizmente, isso implicaria em alterações no código que abre o popup, e parte dele é de domínio de terceiros. Por esse mesmo motivo, não poderia usar parâmetros de querystring também.

Answer (score 1):

Eu achei essa informação na [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/0c014e78-8d35-4df3-93da-7f6a30b4ed8b/object-windowopenerlocationhref-is-malfunctioning-in-ie8?forum=iewebdevelopment) é uma questão de segurança mesmo.

Eu usaria a abordagem de quando for necessário abrir o popup colocaria em uma [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) usando [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/) ou um outro framework.

Abrir popup é complicado, tente evitar ao máximo, pois, tem a questão dos bloqueadores de popup instalados nos browsers.

Comment: Obrigado pela referência do problema na MSDN, vou incluir na pergunta :)

Answer (score -1):

Direto da MDN:

[window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener)

Uso:

```
var parentWindow = window.opener;
```

Verifique se a propriedade `window.opener` é nula, se for, é porque não foi aberto por outra janela, se não for nula, então é porque foi aberta por uma outra janela.

Vale ressaltar que isso não faz parte de nenhum padrão... como a própria MDN diz.

**Nota:**
Como explicado [neste post em inglês](http://blog.shaftek.org/2005/05/05/browser-differences-in-windowopener-behavior/), alguns browsers podem acabar setando a propriedade para nulo, se a janela mãe for fechada. Neste caso, recomendo que a verificação seja feita logo que a página popup for aberta, e o valor armazenado em uma variável qualquer.

Comment: Desculpe, mas citei na pergunta que já uso esse atributo mas tenho encontrado problemas com o IE.

Comment: @EvertonAgner Como você disse que o valor não está sendo preenchido, eu sugeri que você leia o valor o mais cedo possível, e armazene numa variável se é ou não um popup... isso também não funciona?

Comment: O problema é que as configurações de segurança padrão do IE normalmente geram alguns bloqueios em requisições cross-domain. Uma delas é nunca preencher o atributo opener.